ST VNQ9080 continuous current unclear from datasheet
I'm looking to use the ST VNQ9080AJ in a new design, which has current limited outputs at 13.6 amps. But it is unclear to me what the nominal continuous current is that the device can handle.
Since nominal current is not mentioned in the datasheet, can I assume that I can draw 10 amps continuously on a single channel without problems? Since the device has 4 channels, that would mean that the device should be able to source 40A combined which seems like a lot of power...

The datasheet has the following in section 3 Protections:

3.1 Power limitation
The basic working principle of this protection consists of an indirect measurement of the junction temperature swing ΔTJ through the direct measurement of the spatial temperature gradient on the device surface in order to automatically shut off the output MOSFET as soon as ΔTJ exceeds the safety level of ΔTJ_SD. According to the voltage level on the FaultRST pin, the output MOSFET switches on and cycles with a thermal hysteresis according to the maximum instantaneous power which can be handled (FaultRST = Low) or remains off (FaultRST = High). The protection prevents fast thermal transient effects and, consequently, reduces thermo-mechanical fatigue

Therefore, the maximum continuous current will be limited by the junction temperature rise which is a combination of:

The power dissipated in the output MOSFETS, according to the output current and on-state resistance of the MOSFETs. The datasheet has curves for how the on-state resistance varies with temperature and VCC.
The maximum ambient temperature.
The thermal resistance of the VNQ9080AJ package and optional heatsink. The datasheet includes information for the thermal resistance, including options for Heatsink copper area dimension on the PCB.

In summary, there isn't a single maximum continuous current as it depends on a number of factors.
